# Calling a program from /etc/rc.local

Tags: raspbian, linux, script

I have a simple script that adjusts the monitor's brightness that is set to run on startup.

```
#!/bin/bash

gpio -g 18 1024
gpio -g mode pwm
gpio pwmc 1000
gpio -g 18 800
```

I am calling this script from `/etc/rc.local`.

It seems to work and after booting up, it adjusts the brightness before getting to login, but after I log in the screen goes dark, i.e., it looks like GPIO pin `18` is reset to `0`. To fix this, I have to bring up a terminal and manually run the script to readjust the brightness.

An easy enough way to deal with this appears to be simply manually running the script again after logging in or maybe calling it from `$HOME/.profile`, but I would prefer a more permanent solution that makes the adjustment system-wide.

[**EDIT**]:

Adding the script to `$HOME/.profile` did not do the trick. It looks like some other script is called after that turns the screen dark again (possibly resetting GPIO `18` to `0`).

Comment: You are going to have to give us more info, please edit your question and include the following: the code you are using, a short explanation of why you need this and finally your exact question - it appears you want to know how to do this but never actually ask.

Comment: If something else is manipulating GPIO 18 it is because you have requested the change.  We can't magically guess what changes you have made to do this.  However I will point out that audio may also affect GPIO 18.

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). Following the recommendation of the developers from systemd you should avoid using it. In particular it doesn't respect dependencies of starting services. This seems to be the case here.

Comment: @joan: As far as I know, nothing else should be manipulating that pin. Nothing else is installed and I haven't really messed with GPIO until now.

Comment: @Ingo: is /etc/profile a better place to start the program?

Comment: The best is to use a systemd Unit file to define a new service that starts your script. Then you can set dependencies. But as long as you don't know what program reset your monitor settings it's not very helpful. Have you had a look into `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`? `/etc/profie` is the systemwide initialization file, executed for login shells. As long as you are not logged in with `bash` the file isn't executed. I don't know if it is the case with your setup.